# ASP.NET Core MVC MiddlewareFilter exception not meaningful

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Currently I have a problem with thrown exceptions when enabling my MiddlewareFilter. As soon as I add the filter even the developer exceptions are quite meaningless (the complete stacktrace is missing).

```
services.AddMvc(options => options.Filters.Add(new MiddlewareFilterAttribute(typeof(MyFilter))))

public class MyFilter
{
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder applicationBuilder, RequestLocalizationOptions options)
    {
        applicationBuilder.UseRequestLocalization(options);
    }
}
```

Stacktrace with filter:

```
System.Exception: Test Exception
           at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.MiddlewareFilterBuilder.<>c.<<BuildPipeline>b__8_0>d.MoveNext()
        --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
           at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.RequestLocalizationMiddleware.<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()
        --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
           at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>d__22.MoveNext()
        --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
           at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
           at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
           at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeAsync>d__20.MoveNext()
        --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
           at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()
        --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
           at Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression.ResponseCompressionMiddleware.<Invoke>d__3.MoveNext()
        --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
           at SimpleInjector.SimpleInjectorAspNetCoreIntegrationExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<<UseSimpleInjectorAspNetRequestScoping>b__0>d.MoveNext()
        --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
           at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUi.SwaggerUiMiddleware.<Invoke>d__5.MoveNext()
        --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
           at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUi.RedirectMiddleware.<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()
        --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
           at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.<Invoke>d__6.MoveNext()
        --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
           at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.StatusCodePagesMiddleware.<Invoke>d__3.MoveNext()
        --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
           at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.BrowserLinkMiddleware.<ExecuteWithFilter>d__7.MoveNext()
        --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
           at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsMiddleware.<Invoke>d__7.MoveNext()
        --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
           at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.<Invoke>d__7.MoveNext()
```

Stacktrace without filter:

```
System.Exception: Test Exception
   at MyProject.MyRepository.<Fetch>d__9.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at MyProject.MyHandler.<Handle>d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at MyProject.MyController.<Index>d__19.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>d__27.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>d__25.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>d__22.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeAsync>d__20.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression.ResponseCompressionMiddleware.<Invoke>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at SimpleInjector.SimpleInjectorAspNetCoreIntegrationExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<<UseSimpleInjectorAspNetRequestScoping>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUi.SwaggerUiMiddleware.<Invoke>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUi.RedirectMiddleware.<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.<Invoke>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.StatusCodePagesMiddleware.<Invoke>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.BrowserLinkMiddleware.<ExecuteWithFilter>d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsMiddleware.<Invoke>d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.<Invoke>d__7.MoveNext()
```

So basically I'm unable to track down exceptions when enabling the filter. Do you have any ideas how to correct this? (I need to use MiddlewareFilters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking the [MiddlewareFilterBuilder implementation](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/Internal/MiddlewareFilterBuilder.cs#L75-L82) looks like this is an "expected"  behavior...

```
// Ideally we want the experience of a middleware pipeline to behave the same as if it was registered,
// in Startup. In this scenario an exception thrown in a middelware later in the pipeline gets propagated
// back to earlier middleware.
// So check if a later resource filter threw an exception and propagate that back to the middleware pipeline.
if (!resourceExecutedContext.ExceptionHandled && resourceExecutedContext.Exception != null)
{
    throw resourceExecutedContext.Exception;
}
```

That explains why you see

```
System.Exception: Test Exception
           at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.MiddlewareFilterBuilder.<>c.<<BuildPipeline>b__8_0>d.MoveNext()
```

instead of

```
System.Exception: Test Exception
   at MyProject.MyRepository.<Fetch>d__9.MoveNext()
```

Also noticed, that above code is in dev branch, but not in master branch in [aspnet/Mvc](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc) repo...

All this seems like a good candidate for question/issue in MVC repo.

Comment: Thanks, I reported that as an issue.